# Javascript Date starts with 1 hour

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a counter that shows how much time you've spent on the site and I use sessionStorage to access the Date object from multiple pages.

The problem is that the counter starts at 01:00:00 even though I initialized the Date with 00:00:00.

Here is my code:

```
function checkTime(){
    if(document.getElementById("clock")[13] == ''){
        var d = new Date('2010-06-11T00:00:00');
        sessionStorage.setItem('time', d);
    }
}

function updateTime(){
    checkTime();
    var nDate = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('time'));
    nDate.setSeconds(nDate.getSeconds() + 1);
    sessionStorage.setItem('time', nDate);
    var hours = (nDate.getHours()<10 ? "0" : "") + nDate.getHours();
    var minutes = (nDate.getMinutes()<10 ? "0" : "") + nDate.getMinutes();
    var seconds = (nDate.getSeconds()<10 ? "0" : "") + nDate.getSeconds();
    var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    document.getElementById("clock").innerText = timeString;

}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: You have to account for your local time zone. Without the trailing "Z" on the date string, the browser may interpret the date as being local and not UTC.

Comment: Get element by ID... 13??

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan My mistake, I forgot that the clock element was inside another element, so I changed it to document.getElementById("clock").innerText[7] now.

Answer (score 0):

It starts at 01:00 due to your timezone (UTC +1 CET Central European Time, Stockholm).
Create your date in the following manner:

```js
const utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0)); // second param is the month-index, it start at 0, so 5 means june
console.log(utcDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the unix timestamp, is really more simple and timezone free.

When user enter on the website

```
var d = new Date().getTime();
sessionStorage.setItem('time', d);
```

then

```
function updateTime(){
    var nDate = new Date().getTime();
    var startDate = sessionStorage.getItem('time');
    var duration = nDate-startDate;
    var seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    document.getElementById("clock").innerText = timeString;

}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```